# Vue 3 VueRouter 4 - Typing in url works locally but not in prod

Tags: vue-router, vuejs3

I am having an issue, but it seems to only be in production. Using Vue 3 and VueRouter 4.

I setup the **router** like this:

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/', name: 'Default', component: homePage },
  { path: '/profile', name: 'Profile', component: profile },
  { path: '/record-editor/:recordId?', name: 'Record Editor', component: recordEditor },
  { path: '/reset-password', name: 'Reset Password', component: resetPassword, query: { userId: 'test', code: 'grig' } },
  { path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*', name: 'Not Found', component: () => import('../views/404.vue') },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});
```

The **app** (main.js) is setup like this:

```
const app = createApp(App);

app.config.devtools = true;
app
  .use(router)
  .use(store)
  .mount('#app');
```

Locally, I can type it `http://localhost:3000/rubbish` and it takes me to the `Not Found` page successfully. This does not work in Production.

When I type in the production url and tack on `/rubbish` I get the following:

*Error message*

```
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

I have a **vite.config.js** file if it matters:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
});
```

I am not sure what setting is missing.  If it helps, this site gets pushed to Azure.

All of the `<router-link>` links work as expected. But say if one link takes me to `mysite.com/search` it successfully goes there. But if I am at `mysite.com` and then add in the url `mysite.com/search` and hit enter, it takes me to that above error message.

Answer (score 1):

I cant Comment (<50 rep), but i think ur server config is wrong. A quick fix might be to use the router in Hashmode:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(),
  routes,
});
```

Comment: Thanks @orbis for the suggestion. It *does* work locally and in prod, but I am not a fan of the hash. Hopefully someone else will comment as to how to configure or what the non-hash way. If no go with that, then I will mark this as the answer!  Welcome to the community.

Comment: @Grandizer. I am not that deep in to backend routing. But i suggest u to check out the vue-router [Docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html#example-server-configurations). There are some example server configurations.

Comment: Or provide more information about your backend :)